# Is there any way to kick off a datastore backup programatically?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

Is there any way to kick off a datastore backup programatically?

Note that I want to backup to Google Cloud storage not local host and I am working in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something useful, the link below can be called using a google auth cookie to kick off a backup task.

```
https://ah-builtin-python-bundle.Your_App_Name.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupToCloud&kind=SOME_KIND&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=SOME_NAME
```

Details of this API [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups)

Details of getting cookie [here](http://krasserm.blogspot.com/2010/01/accessing-security-enabled-google-app.html)